# How to prevent java-doc creation for certain classes

Tags: java, annotations, documentation, javadoc

I'm executing the following command while build generation to generate java-docs on the go

```
javadoc -private <sourcepath>/*.java -d<destination directory>
```

Now I want to exclude certain classes from available in the source-path directory to not get included in the javadoc generation.

I could see that javadoc provides an inline command "excludepackagenames" which might be useful when there are one or two files needs to be excluded. Now that I want to exclude 10 to 20 files, i would not want the executable command to be very long.

Is there any efficient way to exclude these class either via a spring annotation or by an xml entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can [exclude package(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#exclude) by using -exclude option:

> **-exclude  packagename1:packagename2:...**
>   Unconditionally excludes the specified packages and their subpackages from the list formed by -subpackages. It excludes those packages even if they would otherwise be included by some previous or later -subpackages option. For example:
>
> ```
> C:> javadoc -sourcepath C:\user\src -subpackages java -exclude java.net:java.lang
> ```
>
> would include java.io, java.util, and java.math (among others), but would exclude packages rooted at java.net and java.lang. Notice this excludes java.lang.ref, a subpackage of java.lang).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, In my case all the classes are present under the same package. 
Also, i could see that there are some proposed tags but they are still not yet implemented.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/proposed-tags-142378.html

Comment: Well, I found a work around by using the maven javadoc plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/index.html) and using <sourceFileExcludes> tag to filter out the files. This way I cant prevent from frequenty modifying the script that executes the command.